# How to get the Individual campaign id, For each Campaign ID, having fields Post Engagement, Page Engagement, Link Click

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

ttps://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/act_XXXXXX/insights?fields=account_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,adset_id,adset_name,ad_id,ad_name,spend,actions&filtering=[{field: "action_type",operator:"IN", value['link_click','page_engagement','post_engagement']}]&access_token=XXXXXX

I'm trying the above Graph API CURL: For getting the overall post engagement, page Engagement, and Link Clicks, for this account. Can you please help?
`"{ "data": [ { "account_name": "ABCD", "spend": "232", "actions": [ { "action_type": "link_click", "value": "5962" }, { "action_type": "page_engagement", "value": "26525" }, { "action_type": "post_engagement", "value": "26525" } ], "date_start": "2022-07-27", "date_stop": "2022-08-25" } ], "paging": { "cursors": { "before": "xxxx", "after": "xxxx" } } }'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `level` as parameter to Insights API for getting data at required levels.

Supported levels:

- delivery_ad
- politicalad
- ad
- adset
- campaign
- account

Example for fetching data at campaign level -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/act_XXXXXX/insights?
  fields=account_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,adset_id,adset_name,ad_id,ad_name,spend,actions&
  filtering=[{"field": "action_type",operator:"IN", "value":["link_click","page_engagement","post_engagement"]}]&
  level=campaign
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/#levels

Comment: Thanks, Vivek. it working fine. Same how to get the action_destination,action_target_id fields. can you guide the in curl?

Comment: @Learner you can find reference for all fields with possible values [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v14.0)

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/act_xxx/insights?fields=account_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,ad_id,ad_name,video_avg_time_watched_actions,actions,&filtering=[{field: "action_type",operator:"IN", value: ['link_click','page_engagement','post_engagement']},{'field':'action_destination','operator':'CONTAIN','value':'action_destination'}]&level=ad&access_token=xxx&breakdowns=country&time_range={"since":"2021-08-18","until":"2022-08-18"}  -  I'm trying the above mention url action_destination and video_avg_time_watched_actions. In response it not getting. can you please help me?